# How can one pass the contents of a LaTeX environment to a macro?

Tags: macros, environments

I'm working on an exam document class where the user enters in questions something like this:

```
\multiplechoice{Question}
{Answer #1}
{Answer #2}
{Answer #3}
{Answer #4}
{Correct answer}
{Explanation}
```

I'd like to process this information in various ways in one LaTeX run (to create an answer sheet, key, and the test itself), so the questions need to be stored in a macro. The awkwardness comes when one defines:

```
\newcommand{\sectionA}[1]{\newcommand{\putsectionA}{#1}}
```

and then asks the user to put 15 questions as an argument to \sectionA. I'd much rather have those questions be the contents of an environment, like so:

```
\begin{sectionA}
lots of questions
\end{sectionA}
```

Mostly because I find it much easier to keep track of environment declarations than curly brackets. Is it possible to have the contents of an environment get packaged up into a macro?

Edit:

The solution would seem to be to us the `environ` package, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I'm trying:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{foo}{\edef\foot{\BODY}}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
  Store This
\end{foo}
\foot
\end{document}
```

However when running this code `\foot` remains undefined. It actually seems impossible to define any macro using `environ`. Even when not using `\BODY`. For example, replacing the definition above with

```
\NewEnviron{foo}{\newcommand{\foot}{Print me}}
```

still fails. I've also tried `\Collect@Body` from the `environ` package with similar results. Does `\NewEnvrion` somehow prohibit defining new commands?

Comment: You might want to try the [Tex-LaTeX Stack Exchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think correct location for this question is [http://tex.stackexchange.com/][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh hey! Thanks for pointing a newbie in the right direction.

Comment: There's an existing `exam` class on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam), as well. You may already be aware of it, but if not, and if it meets your needs, then it's available.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `environ` package gives you access to the environment body over the `\BODY` macro. You can copy it e.g. using `\let` or `\edef`:

```
\NewEnviron{sectionA}{\global\let\putsectionA\BODY}
```

or

```
\NewEnviron{sectionA}{\xdef\putsectionA{\BODY}}
```

`\xdef` is like a global `\newcommand` but doesn't check if the command existed before and expands its content before the definition. This is important because the definition of `\BODY` will of course change after the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! That makes a lot of sense to me, but for whatever reason the macro where I wish to store the questions remains undefined. I'm not sure this is proper practice, but I've edited my question to include an example of the issue I encountered when trying your suggestion.

Comment: @Silver: I forgot that the code is executed as part of the environment and is therefore grouped! This means that you need to use `\global\let` or `\xdef` instead. I will update my answer.

Comment: This didn’t quite work for me: it breaks when the environment body given includes `\vspace`, or other macros that mustn’t be expanded too early.  Modifying it to `\NewEnviron{sectionA}{\xdef\putsectionA{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}}` fixes this, making it more closely equivalent to `\newcommand{\putsectionA}{ […stuff…] }`, since then the stuff passed as the body doesn’t get expanded until it’s later invoked with `\putsectionA`.