# Place table at end of chapter

Tags: floats

I have a very large tabular which I want placed at the end of my chapter. I need it inside a float because I want a caption. I could simply put the code at the end of the chapter and use [h] or even [h!] placement modifier. But I'd prefer to keep the code at a different location in the text. I do not want to use a package like endfloat since this is the only float I wish to stick at the end of a chapter.

Comment: a) captions are possible outside floats; see the `capt-of` package and its `\captionof{<type>}{<caption text>}` command. b) Is there a special reason why you don't want to use positioning arguments?

Comment: Try `\floatpagefraction=0` -- I don't know exactly.

Comment: Should the table appear on its own page?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes. Although, it is already big enough to do so.
lockstep: Thanks for the tip. There is no real reason. It just makes sense for the table to occur at one point in the source, but at the end of the chapter in the typeset document.
MarcoDaniel: The problem with solutions like these is that they apply to ALL floats. I only wish to change the placement of a single float.

Comment: And if you simply use `[p]` as the placement specifier, asin `\begin{table}[p]...\end{table}`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Well, it gets placed on its own page, but it does not get pushed to the end of the chapter.

Comment: @Dan yes, my bad. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following setup delays the placement of a *single* float to the end of a chapter. The [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) allows to capture the contents of an environment into a macro (see [How can one pass the contents of a LaTeX environment to a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14392/5764)). Making sure that any banked/stored float is flushed `\AtEndDocument`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\let\chapendfigure\relax
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\chapendfigure\oldchapter}
\AtEndDocument{\chapendfigure}
\NewEnviron{chapendfig}{%
  \global\let\chapendfigureBODY\BODY%
  \gdef\chapendfigure{%
      \begin{figure}\chapendfigureBODY\end{figure}%
        \let\chapendfigure\relax%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}
  \centering\rule{.8\textwidth}{.2\textwidth}\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{chapendfig}
  \centering\rule{.8\textwidth}{.2\textwidth}\caption{Another figure}
\end{chapendfig}
%\show\chapendfigure
%\show\chapendfigureBODY
\lipsum[1-25]
\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

The final figure positioning can be changed inside the `\chapendfigure` macro (defined inside the `chapendfig` environment. Even though the above example delays a `figure`, it can be used for `table` (or any other float) as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the body of your chapter, put the tabular in a `\savebox`

```
\newsavebox{\abcd}
\savebox{\abcd}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b \\
c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

Use the saved box at the end of the chapter in a `table` environment

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\usebox{\abcd}
\caption{a table}\label{t:abc}
\end{table}
```