# newenvironment using pgfplotstable

Tags: environments, pgfplotstable

I want to have a `newenvironment` body as an inline input argument for `pgfplotstable`. Is it possible to do this without using braces in the body itself?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newenvironment{customtabular}
{
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=tab,
    row sep=\\,
    string type,
    ]
}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{customtabular}
{foo    bar\\} %tab here
\end{customtabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The *environ* package should be able to do this.

Comment: Care to give a working example? I get the error **Package pgfplots Warning: You requested to open table 'foo bar\\', but there is
 also a 'foo bar\\.tex'.** Adding **format=inline** "works", but the table will not show up.

Comment: I have (as usual) trouble with TeX expansions.  But this might help.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14390/how-can-one-pass-the-contents-of-a-latex-environment-to-a-macro/14392#14392

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\def\pgfplotstabletypeset@env{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{%  
        \pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@env
    }{%
        \pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@env[]%
    }%
}
\long\def\pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@env[#1]{%
    \begingroup
    \ifpgfplots@table@options@areset
    \else
        \pgfplotstableset{#1}%
    \fi
    \pgfplotstablecollectoneargwithpreparecatcodes{%
        \pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@collectarg@env[#1]%
    }%
}
\long\def\pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@collectarg@env[#1]#2\end{%
    \pgfplotstable@isloadedtable{#2}%
        {\pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@[#1]{#2}}%
        {\pgfplotstabletypesetfile@opt@[#1]{#2}}%
    \end
}

\begin{pgfplotstabletypeset@env}[col sep=space,row sep=\\,string type]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed augue \\
    sem, sollicitudin quis mauris sed, \\
    mattis aliquet diam. Aenean ultricies \\
    orci a ipsum imperdiet condimentum. \\
    Vivamus hendrerit consequat maximus. Ut \\
    auctor dignissim felis in faucibus. \\
    Proin quis vulputate arcu. Praesent \\
    iaculis consequat eros rutrum gravida. \\
    Duis nec volutpat enim, at \\
    fermentum quam. Pellentesque laoreet enim \\
    et neque fermentum luctus. end\\
\end{pgfplotstabletypeset@env}

\end{document}
```

## Explanation

In `pgfplotstable.code.tex` line 1310-1331:

> ```
> \def\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
>   \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{%  
>       \pgfplotstabletypeset@opt
>   }{%
>       \pgfplotstabletypeset@opt[]%
>   }%
> }
> \long\def\pgfplotstabletypeset@opt[#1]{%
>   \begingroup
>   \ifpgfplots@table@options@areset
>   \else
>       \pgfplotstableset{#1}%
>   \fi
>   \pgfplotstablecollectoneargwithpreparecatcodes{%
>       \pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@collectarg[#1]%
>   }%
> }
> \long\def\pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@collectarg[#1]#2{%
>   \pgfplotstable@isloadedtable{#2}%
>       {\pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@[#1]{#2}}%
>       {\pgfplotstabletypesetfile@opt@[#1]{#2}}%
> }
> ```

This shows that braces in `{table & contents \\}` are mandatory because it becomes the second parameter of `\pgfplotstabletypeset@opt@collectarg`. But we can change the argument pattern --- by `[#1]#2\end` we mean that the second parameter is from `]` to `\end`. Notice that right after the `\end` there should be `{pgfplotstabletypeset@env}`. After typesetting the table, we put back another `\end` so LaTeX can end the environment `pgfplotstabletypeset@env`.