# How does the stripcommand in the pgfmanual file work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, sourcecode

I am trying to understand how commands are typeset for use in LaTeX documentation. To clarify, *not* using LaTeX to create documentation, rather to write documentation in LaTeX about using LaTeX (like in the manuals). As far as I am aware, there is no term of this to distinguish LaTeX documentation from creating documentation with LaTeX (unfortunately).

## Lines 1099-1121 of the pgfmanual-en-macros.tex

*https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en*

This code "looks like" it removes at signs to me, but I don't know. Why is this necessary? How does it work?

```
{
  \makeatletter
  \global\let\myempty=\@empty
  \global\let\mygobble=\@gobble
  \catcode`\@=12
  \gdef\getridofats#1@#2\relax{%
    \def\getridtest{#2}%
    \ifx\getridtest\myempty%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\strippedat\expandafter{\strippedat#1}
    \else%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\strippedat\expandafter{\strippedat#1\protect\printanat}
      \getridofats#2\relax%
    \fi%
  }

  \gdef\removeats#1{%
    \let\strippedat\myempty%
    \edef\strippedtext{\stripcommand#1}%
    \expandafter\getridofats\strippedtext @\relax%
  }

  \gdef\stripcommand#1{\expandafter\mygobble\string#1}
}
```

## Reasoning

The reason why I would like to understand this is because I seem to be able to typeset commands with the following code. I suspect there are cases when the my idea will not work.

There are also limitations:

- include commands with arguments such that I can typeset them (in `NewEnviron` with `#1`) as an example under the explanation (e.g. \hello{input1} and then using `#1` in the `NewEnviron` would not work)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{command}[1]{% 
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\texttt{\string#1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}
\BODY
\end{minipage}
\xdef\putcommandexample{\BODY}% Set BODY to variable http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14392/13552
}%
\begin{document}
\section{Friendly Commands}
\begin{command}{\hello}
This command greets the reader in a friendly manner.
\end{command}
\begin{command}{\goodbye}
This command greets the reader in a friendly manner.
\end{command}
\end{document}
```

Sidenote for anybody interested: Instead of `minipage`s I also put the commands in the margin using the `marginnote` package. It looks alright.

```
\NewEnviron{command}[1]{% 
\reversemarginpar\marginnote{\texttt{\string#1}}
\BODY
\par
}%
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Actually, the `\getridofats` command replaces `@` with `\protect\printanat`.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Ok thanks!  I fixed my statement above.

Comment: In particular if you want to mention a command such as `\pgf@with@alotof@ats@in@it` it is useful.

Comment: `tcolorbox` also includes a library for typing `documentation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question *“why is it necessary?”* would require reading all the documentation source. How it works is easy to see.

The macro `\getridofats` decides whether what follows it in the input stream up to `\relax` contains a category code 12 `@`.

However, it's better to see how `\removeats` works to begin with. It should receive a command name as its ***braced*** argument; first of all it initializes `\strippedat` to an empty token list. Then it does

```
\edef\strippedtext{\stripcommand#1}
```

which sets `\strippedtext` to a string containing the command name with the backslash stripped off it, because it does

```
\expandafter\mygobble\string#1
```

For example, `\removeats{\abc@def}` does `\expandafter\mygobble\string\abc@def` that first transforms `\abc@def` into a string of category 12 characters (but category code 11 for letters appearing after `@`, if the macro is called in a `\makeatother` context) and then `\mygobble` eats up the backslash.

After this preparation, `\expandafter\getridofats\strippedtext @\relax` is called, which produces the following tokens in the input stream:

```
\getridofats abc@def@\relax
```

Looking at the definition of `\getridofats`, we see that `#1` is `abc`, while `#2` is `def@`. If the call `\removeats{\abcdef}` had been seen, the input stream would contain

```
\getridofats abcdef@\relax
```

and `#1` would be `abcdef`, while `#2` would be empty.

The macro `\getridtest` is defined to expand to `#2`; in the first case it's not empty, in the second case it is.

After this, `\ifx\getridtest\myempty` returns true in the second case, false in the first case.

Assume the test returnes true (second case). Then

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\strippedat\expandafter{\strippedat abcdef}
```

is performed, which appends `#1` (in this case `abcdef`) to the previous value of `\strippedat`. It might appear useless, because `\strippedat` had been initialized to empty. But we'll see later what happens in the “false” case.

Suppose the test returnes false (first case). Then

```
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\strippedat\expandafter{\strippedat abc\protect\printanat}%
  \getridofats def@\relax
```

is done: the first piece is appended to `\strippedat`, then `\protect\printanat` and the macro `\getridofats` is called back to process the final chunk.

Not a particularly well written macro, in my opinion. However, the calls

```
\removeats\abcdef
\removeats\abc@def
\removeats\ab@cd@ef
```

result in `\strippedat` to contain, respectively,

```
abcdef
abc\protect\printanat def
ab\protect\printanat cd\protect\printanat ef
```

where `\printanat` is defined by

```
\def\printanat{\char`\@}
```

Of course `\protect` is definitely not needed provided the macro is defined with `\def\printanat{\char64 }`, but that's a personal choice. As the documentation is processed with LaTeX, I'd probably have opted for

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\printanat}{\char`\@ }
```

(note the trailing space, it's wrong not having it).

Apparently the mechanism is used for avoiding to write `@` characters in the `.aux` file so avoiding problems with its category code (which is set to 11 when reading LaTeX auxiliary files).

---

`expl3` version, to be issued in a context where `@` has category code 12.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \removeats #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \strippedat { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \strippedat { @ } { \protect\printanat }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Just a minor point, but without braces around the macro argument,`\removeats\ab@cd@ef` will only work as stated if the category code of `@` is 11.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Indeed, the call must be `\removeats{\whatever}` *with* braces. I've stated it in the answer.