# Putting custom environment (using environ package) start and ends in commands

Tags: macros, environments

I was trying to write an environment using the
[`environ` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ). The new environment
can be defined without any problem. For some personal reasons, I want to
put the start and end of environments to some macros.

See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{workpl@n}{\BODY}[\relax]

% The following will not pose any problem
% \newenvironment{workpl@n}{\relax}{\relax}

\def\beginworkplan{\begin{workpl@n}}
\def\endworkplan{\end{workpl@n}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Does not work
% \beginworkplan

\makeatletter
% Works 
\begin{workpl@n}

Plan

% Works 
\end{workpl@n}

% Does not work
% \endworkplan
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Strangely, `\beginworkplan`, `\endworkplan` command pair fails
with the message:

> ! LaTeX Error: \begin{workpl@n} on input line 14 ended by
>   \end{document}.

However, if the environment is started and finished directly (using `\begin{workpl@n}`
and `\end{workpl@n}`), it also works.

Moreover, if a new environment is defined using the basic `\newenvironment` command,
putting the start and end of environments to`\beginworkplan` and `\endworkplan`
does not pose any problem at all.

I need to use `\NewEnviron` since I have the necessity to [collect the
environment body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14392/14103).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that an environment defined with `\NewEnviron` *has* to see `\end` in order to determine the extent of the body.

However, you don't need `environ` for your purpose, but I surely cannot recommend doing things this way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\beginworkplan#1\endworkplan{%
  whatever with #1% #1 here is the same as \BODY with \NewEnviron
}

\begin{document}

\beginworkplan
Plan
\endworkplan
\makeatother

\end{document}
```