# How to plug in value from custom environment command

Tags: environments

In learning how to use custom environments, I would like to try to do the following. Here is my setup:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{
  \let\mycaption\myns@mycaption

  \begin{figure}[!h]
  \caption{???whatgoeshere???}
  \end{figure}
}{}
```

In the `???whatgoeshere???` block, I would like to plugin the value of `\mycaption`. So for example say this is how it's used:

```
\begin{myenv}
  \mycaption{Hello world}
\end{myenv}
```

The question is, how you plug that into the `\caption{...}`. Something like:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{
  \let\mycaption\myns@mycaption

  \begin{figure}[!h]
  \if @mycaption is filled out
  \caption{@mycaption}
  \fi
  \end{figure}
}{}
```

**Update**

Basically, I want to take the contents of any command used inside of an environment, and place it somewhere within the `newenvironment` command. So

```
\newenvironment{myexample}{
  \let\a\...
  \let\b\...
  \let\c\...

  % place the first `a` here, if it was used in the environment
  \a:first

  % place all of the b's here
  \b:all

  % place all of the c's here
  \c:all

  % place the rest of the a's here
  \a:n+1
}{}
```

And it would be used like:

```
\begin{myexample}
  \a{My first item}
  \a{My second item}
  \a{My third item...}
  \b{Foo}
  \c{1}
  \b{Bar}
  \c{2}
  \c{3...}
\end{myexample}
```

But the output (because of the `\newenvironment` definition) would be:

```
My first item
Foo
Bar
1
2
3...
My second item
My third item...
```

Wondering how to accomplish this sort of behavior. This way, the *usage* of the `myexample` wouldn't care about the order of the operations, you just put `\a` `\b`, etc. wherever. Then the `\newenvironment` code would place them in the appropriate positions.

Not even sure how to get started in placing the values in different positions. Once that makes sense then it should probably be straightforward to figure out the details of placing the first/nth-one wherever.

Comment: As  always on this site, please provide  a full minimal example. Besides that, I do not understand what it is you're trying to do

Comment: This seems related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14390/how-can-one-pass-the-contents-of-a-latex-environment-to-a-macro

Comment: You just make macros that store the data, and then typeset it at the end part of the env. The hard part is of course to figure out a good way to store this, does all the `\b` and `\c` data come before the second `\b` is typeset? You could probably use lists from the `etoolbox` package to implement this, looping over the a list and determining when you are typesetting the first element and at what post loop over the b and c lists. It can probably be done neatly in expl3

Comment: That sounds interesting, would love to understand more how to implement what you're describing.

Comment: @daleif this seems along the lines of what you're describing http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/getitems/getitems.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point (this site is not a do it for me service), see the `etoolbox` manual for details. Here I'm not even using an environment (the `memoir` class is irrelevant, it is just the default class in my editor)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{first}
\toggletrue{first}

\newcommand\aaaList{}
\newcommand\aaa[1]{\listadd\aaaList{#1}}

\newcommand\typesetAitem[1]{
  #1\par
  \iftoggle{first}{
    do something after first item
    \togglefalse{first}
  }{}
  \par
}
\newcommand\typesetA{\forlistloop\typesetAitem\aaaList}

\begin{document}

\aaa{Test 1}
\aaa{Test 2}
\aaa{Test 3}

\typesetA

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! This is very helpful, thank you. There is a lot of clever stuff going on there.

Comment: @LancePollard for notive LaTeX programmers `etoolbox` and `xparse` are packages worth taking a loot at.