# How can I define the command as the inwards of the environment?

Tags: environments

How can I put the inwards of the environment into the command?

For example I use

```
\begin{tmpenv}
\a

\b

\c

\end{tmpenv}
```

I want to get the result similar to

```
\long\def\tmpenv{%
\a

\b

\c
}
```

to be able to use \tmpenv several times with various definitions of \a, \b, \c:

```
\def\a{aaa}
\def\b{bbb}
\def\c{ccc}

\tmpenv

\def\a{AAA}
\def\b{BBB}
\def\c{CCC}

\tmpenv
```

will give

```
aaabbbccc

AAABBBCCC
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain why you want to use that? What do you want to realise with that? Could be you have here a XY-problem ...

Comment: You might be looking for the [`environ` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/environ?lang=de). It stores the environment content into its own `\BODY` macro. Or are you trying to achieve the opposite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one pass the contents of a LaTeX environment to a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14390/how-can-one-pass-the-contents-of-a-latex-environment-to-a-macro)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

the `b` argument type places body as an argument in `#1` which you can then save as `\foo`. (`+` allows `\par`/blank lines)

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tmpenv}{+b}
{\long\gdef\foo{#1}}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tmpenv}
\a

\b

\c

\end{tmpenv}

\def\a{aaa}
\def\b{bbb}
\def\c{ccc}

\foo

\def\a{AAA}
\def\b{BBB}
\def\c{CCC}

\foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you really want `aaabbbccc` then you will need to locally define `\par` to be empty as you have `\par` saved the the environment body.

Answer (score 1):

A classic LaTeX2e solution employing the `environ` package could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\newtoks\tmpenvtoks
\newcommand*\tmpenvstore{\the\tmpenvtoks}

\NewEnviron{tmpenv}{%
  \global\tmpenvtoks\expandafter{\BODY}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tmpenv}
\a

\b

\c

\end{tmpenv}

\def\a{aaa}
\def\b{bbb}
\def\c{ccc}

\tmpenvstore

\def\a{AAA}
\def\b{BBB}
\def\c{CCC}

\tmpenvstore
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You only need `\global\tmpenvtoks\expandafter{\BODY}`, without the extra `\expandafter`s.

Comment: Thank you, @StevenB.Segletes! (Still tossing those `\expandafter`s like coins to our witcher...)